# Get current working directory of all drives on WIndows using C++

Tags: visual-c++, python-2.7

I'm trying to duplicate the os.path.abspath() behavior of python in Visual C++. Here's where it get's tricky: I have 2 or more drives, say C: and U: for example. In my shell I do a cd U:/udir. pwd gives U:/udir. Then I do a cd C:/cdir. pwd now gives C:/cdir.

Now I open python and say
os.path.abspath('U:newdir/file.ext')

and it prints U:/udir/newdir/file.ext. My question is using Windows API or native C++ calls only, how do I get the current working directory of U: if my application is running on C:.

GetCurrentDirectory or _getcwd does not accept drives so I'm at a lost.

Comment: But why do you need that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [GetFullPathName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364963%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (that's what used by Python on Windows). The documentation doesn't explicitly mentions the possibility to use a drive-specific "current directory", but that's how it works.